# TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not iterable-BaseHttpServer issue

Tags: python, postgresql, basehttpserver

I set up a basic python webserver using BaseHttpServer and am practicing querying data from a postgresql database. Everything is going swimmingly, but I have an error when I'm parsing the SQL results. 
Here is my code:

```
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute(('select * from stop_times as a, stop_times as b where a.train_id=b.train_id and a.station_name = %s and b.station_name= %s and a.arrival_time < b.arrival_time'), (origin_name, dest_name))

self.wfile.write("Train Number &nbsp &nbsp  Starting Station &nbsp &nbsp  Destination Station &nbsp &nbsp Departure Time &nbsp &nbsp Arrival Time <br />")

while True:
    row=cur.fetchone()
    if row==None:
        break

    print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

    for item in row[0]:
        self.wfile.write("%s"% item)
    self.wfile.write(" &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp")
    for item in row[3]:
        self.wfile.write("%s"% item)
    self.wfile.write(" &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp")

    for item in row[8]:                         
        self.wfile.write("%s"% item)
    self.wfile.write("&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp")

    for item in row[2]:
        self.wfile.write("%s"% item)
    self.wfile.write("&nbsp &nbsp")
```

The print statement is there for debugging to the console, and it gives the correct output:

```
427 10:23:00 10:23:00 San Antonio 6 427 11:08:00 11:08:00 Millbrae
429 11:23:00 11:23:00 San Antonio 6 429 12:08:00 12:08:00 Millbrae
431 12:23:00 12:23:00 San Antonio 6 431 13:08:00 13:08:00 Millbrae
```

I'm just trying to output certain columns to the web page, and when I get to that last for loop for row[2] I get this error:

```
File "./caltrainServer.py", line 129, in performQuery
for item in row[2]:
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object is not iterable
```

I checked, and those columns in my database are of type interval. How do I iterate through them like I did with my other columns, which were of type varchar?

Comment: `row[2]` is a 'datetime.timedelta', you cannot get 'item' from within it (as it only has itself). I don't think you need to do any iterations, could you just `self.wfile.write("{0}, {1}... {9}".format(row[0], row[1]... row[9]))` ?

Comment: did you intend for the html entity `&nbsp;` ( not `&nbsp` ) ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I should've typed &nbsp;

Comment: GordonsBeard: That's a much better way of outputting the format, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unnecessarily iterating over the contents of the row values.  Lines like this:

```
for item in row[0]:
    self.wfile.write("%s"% item)
```

Could likely be changed to

```
self.wlfile.write(row[0])
```

What you are doing, when `row[x]` is a string is actually iterating over each letter and writing it.  But `row[2]` is a datetime.datetime object.  And since datetime.datetime objects are not iterable, you get that error message.

Try instead something like:

```
self.wlfile.write((row[2]))
```

That places the datetime object in a tuple which can be iterated.